# This mysql statement is not working,

Tags: javascript, mysql

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM queue_stats
WHERE qevent = 11 AND 'datetime' < NOW() LIMIT 20");
```

I have a table column called 'datetime' with date format(YYYY-MM-DD H:M:S)
And I want to get 20 query results with dates before now, i.e. the time the query was made. How can I make the **'datetime' < NOW()** produce the required result. When I use this mysql statement, I always get a blank page with no result. Please help.

Comment: Pretty sure you want to use backticks ` not quotes '.

Comment: take out single quote from `AND 'datetime'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`) denote string literals. Thus you're comparing **the string** `'datetime'` to the result of `now()` implicitly converted to a string. You probably meant to use backticks to escape the column name:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   queue_stats
WHERE  qevent = 11 AND `datetime` < NOW() 
       -- Here --------^--------^
LIMIT  20
```

Answer (score 0):

change single quote to apostrophe

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM queue_stats WHERE qevent = 11 AND `datetime` < NOW() LIMIT 20");
```